# How to specify each digit of a real number in decimal representation in set theory?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, logic, real-numbers

So real numbers have decimal representations. If you want to say the $n$th digit of some real number, how do you say this formally in set theory?

Comment: Why do you ask?

Answer (score 2):

If you go straight for the $n$th digit (after the decimal point) of $x$, something like this should work
$$ \left\lfloor 10^{n+1}|x| - 10\left\lfloor 10^n |x|\,\right\rfloor \right\rfloor $$
Encoding the floor function and other necessary arithmetic as set theory is left as an exercise for the reader.

Answer (score 1):

You can consider the decimal expansion to be a sequence of natural numbers.  Then the graph of the sequence can be made into a set
$$
\{(1,x_1),(2,x_2),\ldots \}.
$$
This works nicely for all real numbers between $0$ and $1$.  You can fix it up so that it works for all real numbers.  I should also mention that you have to take equivalence classes.